# Does the function $U=\frac{kx}{(x+x_{0})^2}$ reduce to a simple harmonic potential energy function for small oscillations around $x=x_0$?

Tags: physics, approximation, approximation-theory, linear-approximation

The question is from a physics problems book,

> A particle of mass $m$ moves in a potential energy function given by $$U=\frac{kx}{(x+x_{0})^2}$$ where $x$ denotes the position and $x_0$ is a constant.
>
> 1. What is the stable equilibrium position of the particle?
> 2. What will be the time period of small oscillations about this mean position?

The first part is easy. The answer to the first part is

> $$x=x_0 $$

for stable equilibrium.

The solution is by first differentiating the potential energy function and setting it to zero. We obtain two answers $x_0$ and $-x_0$.

$-x_0$ is rejected as a solution since it is in unstable equilibrium.

The second part of the question is baffling me.

I am unable to prove that the particle will perform SHM for small oscillations around $x=x_0$ even by using approximations.

To prove that a particle performs SHM we can proceed by two cases, both conditions are sufficient by them self.

---

Potential Energy $U$ should be of the form $U=Ax^2+Bx$ where $A>0$

---

Force on the particle should be of the form $F=Px+Q$ where $P<0$

---

**Note that force and potential energy are related by $F=-\frac{dU}{dx}$**

So what is my mathematical question?

**Can you show that the expression $U=\frac{kx}{(x+x_{0})^2}$ reduces to the two cases above by using the fact that the particle is performing *small* oscillations around the point $x=x_0$?**

**I think that some mathematical approximations will be needed to simplify the expression.**

I graphed the function on Desmos and what I saw was [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4hotrjgt5q). By adjusting the sliders you can see that the graph has a infinite well or infinite peak. I don't think any particle can perform SHM in such a potential energy distribution. Usually for SHM the potential energy distribution is of a form where there is a finite well in the graph like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4mhajfdwnj).

The answer given in the book is

> $$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{2mx_{0}^3}{k}}$$

Comment: Are you sure the answer is that

Comment: @neonpokharkar No, I am not sure. That's why I asked this question. According to the book that is the answer but I don't feel that way. I am not even convinced that the particle will perform SHM at all.

Comment: you can Taylor expand the function around the minimum that you have found, up to the second term it will give you a quadratic; and are you sure that **this** is your function, because as you put it here, I don't see any stable equilibrium points - there's one unstable ($x_0$), and one which is not in the domain at all ($-x_0$). Forgot a minus sign maybe?

Comment: @NickPavlov No I am quite sure it is $x=x_0$ since in the book's answer key also it is given as $x=x_0$ and not $x=-x_0$.

Comment: my question was whether you copied the $U$ correctly. This $U$ does not have any local minima for positive values of $k$ (as you have seen on your plot)

Comment: @NickPavlov Yes, its quite possible I may be wrong. I am checking it again. But the book does say that $x=x_0$ is the answer.

Comment: $x = x_0$ can be the answer for many other potential functions - any function that has a local minimum there - but certainly not for this one.

Comment: for future reference: you can use Wolfram to Taylor expand: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+kx%2F(x%2Ba)%5E2+at+x%3Da (you can see that the $(x-a)^2$ coefficient is negative, so unstable equilibrium)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68773/discussion-between-deltascuti-fomalhautb-and-nick-pavlov).

Answer (score 1):

$$F=\frac{d}{dx}\Big(\frac{kx}{(x+x_0)^2}\Big)=\frac{-kx+kx_0}{(x+x_0)^3}=0$$
.: $$x=x_0$$
So,
$$a=\frac{-kx+kx_0}{m(x+x_0)^3}$$
At $x=x_0$$$x+x_0\approx 2x_0$$and$$x =x_0+\delta x$$.:$$a=-\frac{k}{m(2x_0)^3}\delta x$$

Comment: except that actually should have $F = -dU/dx$

Comment: @NickPavlov Exactly! That's why its not possible for it to be in SHM.

Comment: @DeltaScuti_Fomalhautb This is in all likelihood, a mistake - either in the book itself, or in copying the formula from the book - **in the formula for the potential.**

Comment: @NickPavlov Yes, it seems to be that. Thanks for your help! I needed confirmation from someone that this was a mistake.